# PHP File Writing

Tags: php, file

How do you save the file name to be like this:

> submittion_Day/Month/Year/Hour/Minute.txt

I currently have tried:

```
$date = date("d/m/y");
$time = date("h:i:a");

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/United_Kingdom");

$file = fopen("submission" . $date . $time . ".txt", "w");
```

Thanks

Comment: So, does that work?  Not work?  Do you see any errors?  Is a file created?  What does `echo "submission" . $date . $time . ".txt";` show you?

Comment: P.S. `/` are directory separators.  You'll probably need to use `mkdir()` to create those sub-folders if they do not already exist.

Comment: It's not good practice to put slashes in your file name.  They could be interpreted as directory separators.

Comment: make sure that your platform lets you save it like that

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm having trouble understanding what exactly they want to do here. Save it as different folders according to the variable(s), or as an actual filename with the slashes etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Pretty sure you can't have slashes in filenames, but maybe that differs per-filesystem...

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ditto on that, which is what I told the OP. Doubting we're going to get anymore feedback here. *Magic answers* will not be coming from me anytime soon ;-)

Comment: I was right (so far) @RocketHazmat - OP's probably gone to get us all some lunch too!? Just like a baseball player "stealing home" and getting caught for it, *I am outta here....*. arrivederci.

Comment: When I enter the above code it doesn't create a file. Without the date and time in the name it records all the text perfectly. The / was just to separate it in the text to space it out. All I would like is the file name to have date and time within it. Anyone know how to?

Comment: @JackMoseley: Instead of `/`, use a different character.

Answer (score 0):

Update: File names cannot have / so changed to - and worked perfectly. Thanks for everyones help :)